# How do I create a scrollable div that matches the height of my `iframe` using Material-UI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I am creating a responsive Video Player with a playlist next to it. This is for Desktop and above screens sizes. The playlist can have hundreds of items.

My attempt is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-video-player-playlist-q3601

The problem that I am facing is when there are a lot of items, the playlist part is not scrollable and its height does not match with its sibling (video-player).

**What I am looking for**
- That the height of the player & playlist should be equal to the height of the video player.
- A large number of items in the playlist should be scrollable.

**What have I tried?**
The demo is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-video-player-playlist-q3601

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the same trick for the playlist and the player , a break point and position.

adding a class can help add a few more CSS rules :

https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-video-player-playlist-i1msg

CSS part updated :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "brown",
    display: "flex"
  },
  playerContainer: {
    position: "relative",
    paddingTop: "37.25%",
    height: 0,
    overflow: "hidden",
    maxWidth: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      paddingTop: "56.25%"
    }
  },
  iframe: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    border: "6px solid yellow"
  },
  playlist: {
    position: "relative",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      position: "staic"
    }
  },
  playlistContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "0",
    bottom: "0",
    right: "0",
    left: "0",
    overflow: "auto",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      position: "relative"
    }
  }
}));
```

and structure :

```
<Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={8} className={classes.playerContainer}>
        <iframe
          title="video"
          src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/66140585"
          frameborder="0"
          className={classes.iframe}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4} className={classes.playlist}>
        <Grid container className={classes.playlistContainer}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            {lines.map((line, key) => (
              <div key={key}>{line}</div>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much! This is exactly what was missing!